# How to stream app logs to a cloud platform

Tags: spring-boot, cloudfoundry-java-client

Hi I am looking on how to stream application logs from a Spring boot application to a cloud. To elaborate:- Suppose I have a spring app to be deployed as a pcf application for which I need to send the logs generated from the application to an external cloud platform.

Comment: What logging framework do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure appenders for loggers like logback, log4j2 to stream logs on external cloud platforms like aws cloudwatch with ease.